# how stackoverflow is making url

Tags: url-rewriting, url-routing

i need to know how stack overflow is creating the url in name of title as an page.. 
if i ask an question as `how stackoverflow is making url` is it creating an page for that question or it is coming from db ..if it is from db how it is done....

Comment: [What was Stack Overflow built with?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

Comment: I don't agree that this question IS a duplicate. That question doesn't cover the re-writing bits, at a technical level. It might be built into the MVC framework, but that's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @dawmail333: He never said it was a duplicate. I also checked the close votes, there are no duplicate votes (yet).

Answer (score 3):

It's called URL Rewriting, done specifically for the purpose of search engines.

At a guess, I'd say that the ACTUAL url that is being called (logically) is something like this:

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/index.php?id=4591366
```

The text bit probably is only to make identification easier, especially for search engines.

That index.php probably loads the question identified by that id, which in this case, is your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591366/how-stackoverflow-is-making-url
```

> **4591366** -  ID of question
>       **how-stackoverflow-is-making-url**  - a String made from subject after processing it correctly how stackoverflow is making url

while retrieving Question id only is enough, while subject will help in SEO stuff

Answer (score 2):

The number is the primary key.  The part afterwards is ignored when processing actual requests.  So:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591366/
```

and

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591366/made%20up
```

both work.

However, links and redirects are generated that way (by including the title) for search engine optimization.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow uses ASP.NET MVC Routing to achieve its URLs.

They would be using a Routing Map similar to this:

```
"{question}/{id}"
```

Then in the URL they just add the title of the question which gets ignored by their routing logic but gets used for Search Engine Optimisation.

Source: *Hanselminutes Podcast 134 - StackOverflow uses ASP.NET MVC - Jeff Atwood and his technical team*, http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast134StackOverflowUsesASPNETMVCJeffAtwoodAndHisTechnicalTeam.aspx